# Visual Studio Reports does not update dataset based on object binding

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio Reporting Services to create a report that has object binding (and not SQL database). I have created the following class that contains the objects that need to be imported:

```
public class Paper 
 { 

int m_grade;

public Paper()
        {
          m_grade = 1000;
        }

public int Grade
        {
            get { return m_grade; }
        }
}
```

This works fine when I initially bind my report to this class. However, if I add any more methods to this class, such as:

```
 public Paper()
     {
     m_grade = 1000;
     int m_mydummy1 = 12;
    }
```

and add another property

```
    public int MyDummy
    {
    get {return m_dummy1;}
    }
```

it does not get updated in the DataSet that has been automatically generated by the Report Wizard due to which I am unable to add more data/methods to my Reporting Table embedded in the Report. The same happens if I add another Class within the Parent class.

Is there a way around this preferably without having to write code?

Thank you!

Comment: Better show the code which you add more methode to this class ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was with Visual Studio not being able to update internally generated datasets for tables/charts/ etc. To update them, go to the report. When the report is active, The "Report" menu will show up in the menu bar. Go to View->Report Data. This opens up a side pane with datasets that are being used internally. right-click on the dataset you wish to update and click on refresh. This pane can also be used to add new datasets to organize data for charts, tables , etc.

Answer (score 3):

These steps worked for me:

1. Remove data set
2. Close and reopen Visual Studio
3. Add data set again

I'm using VS 2013 ultimate.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (VS2012 Ultimate). If someone can offer a better solution please let me know, or if someone can AT LEAST explain why/how this works. Simply refreshing the dataset the object belongs to has never worked for me

Answer (score 1):

With a .Net SQL Server Reporting Services report we often use an object as a datasource but sometimes a newly added property in the object isn't visible in the report's DataSet
         
        Here are the steps I followed to fix this for my report:

1. Open up the report in Visual Studio and then show the Report Data window - View - Report Data or Ctrl-Alt-D.
2. Expand the DataSources and DataSets branches.
3. Right-click on the DataSet you're using and select Refresh.
4. If this doesn't bring in the new field, do a Clean and Rebuild of the Project which contains your object and try again.
5. If this doesn't work, delete and re-add the DataSet, making sure to call it the same as before for whatever logic binds the report to the DataSource at run time.
6. If all the above doesn't work, delete the DataSet and then delete all the DataSources too before re-adding the DataSet again.

If you want to look under the hood at how the report is hooked up, do a search for <TablixCell> in your report project and it will take you into the rdlc (Report Definition Language - Client) file, there doesn't seem to be another way to open this even if you show all files, unless you open it from explorer. If you then search for your DataSet name you'll see how a few steps which I'll explain:

1. You can see the DataSet name references the DataSource name, and this in turn references the DataSourceID.
2. If you look at the properties of the project containing your object and then select the Assembly Information, you'll see that the DataSourceID is the Guid shown near the bottom of the page.
3. It looks like Visual Studio has some sort of bug here (hopefully addressed by SP1) where these bindings get broken. Removing and re-adding everything clears out all the redundant DataSources seems to resolve this.

<DataSources>
             <DataSource Name="**CodeGeneratorData**">
              <ConnectionProperties>
               <DataProvider>System.Data.DataSet</DataProvider>
               <ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>

              </ConnectionProperties>

             <rd:DataSourceID>**fc9a4d7c-55c6-4f10-9e21-7c9eb5ef7996**</rd:DataSourceID>

            </DataSource>

            </DataSources>

            <DataSets>

             <DataSet Name="**CodeGeneratorDataSet**">

              <Query>

               <DataSourceName>**CodeGeneratorData**</DataSourceName>

               <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
              </Query>